# how do I redirect from a subdirectory to another directory, but strip off the original subdirectory from the URI using mod_rewrite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a Ruby on Rails app running on 12001. I am currently redirecting a subdomain to 127.0.0.1:12001 using some ReWriteCond detection.
Now I want to redirect my subdirectory to that rails app.

```
http[s]://domain.com/redmine
```

to

```
127.0.0.1:12001
```

The current rules apply REQUEST_URI to the above rails path, but I need to strip "/redmine" from the front of REQUEST_URI...

Any ideas?

Comment: I read here http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/apache-mod_rewrite-examples about atoms, but I can't seem to get them to work for me. This is what I have so far.

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/redmine/(.*)$
ReWriteRule ^/?$ http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1:12001/$1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without mod_rewrite.

```
Redirect Permanent /redmine http://127.0.0.1:12001
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: I need rewrite. This is a production environment. Redirecting to 127.0.0.1 redirects to the end-user's machine, not my web server's ruby server.

Comment: You said, "I want to redirect".  Do you really want to use ReverseProxy instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/redmine/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:12001/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If the rule is placed in the Directory directive, then:

```
RewriteRule ^redmine/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:12001/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The parameters at the end:

- [QSA] appends the query string (up to you);
- [L] makes it the last rule

**NB** /redmine will not be matched by this rule, but I am going off what you tried, only subpaths, e.g. /redmine/abc